# How to find that the time-format mode in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, settings, time-format

How can we find the time format (whether 12 hours or 24 hours) mode in iPhone?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this answer by [Micheal Waterfall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106244/michael-waterfall) in this previous SO question [Detect whether iPhone is displaying time in 12-Hour or 24-Hour Mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972108/detect-whether-iphone-is-displaying-time-in-12-hour-or-24-hour-mode)

```
@implementation NSLocale (Misc)
- (BOOL)timeIs24HourFormat {
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
    [formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSRange amRange = [dateString rangeOfString:[formatter AMSymbol]];
    NSRange pmRange = [dateString rangeOfString:[formatter PMSymbol]];
    BOOL is24Hour = amRange.location == NSNotFound && pmRange.location == NSNotFound;
    [formatter release];
    return is24Hour;
}
@end
```

Hope this helps