# I want to Switch Time scrubber to do 15 min intervals

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

Please Suggest me i want to go in 15 minute intervals.
ex: 4:00, 4:15, 4:30, 4:45 and so next.

```
 @IBAction func sliderMoved(sender: UISlider) {

       let slot = Double(sender.value)
       let slotDate = self.timeFromSlot(slot)

       print(timeFormatter.stringFromDate(slotDate!))
    }

    private func timeFromSlot(slot:Double) -> NSDate? {

        let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let unit:NSCalendarUnit = [.Year, .Month, .Day, .Hour, .Minute, .Second]
        let comps = cal.components(unit, fromDate: NSDate())
        comps.hour = Int((slot % (24 * 3600)) / 3600)
        comps.minute = Int(slot % 3600 / 60)
        comps.second = 0

        let startedDate = cal.dateFromComponents(comps)!

        return startedDate
    }
```

I have sliderMoved that starting point is 8:00 AM and end point 9:00 PM i have set slider min value 28,800 and max value 75,600, When i slide the slider the value is change with my timeFromSlot method and the changed value i got in between 8:01 8:02 8:03.. and i want changed value 8:00 8:15 8:30 like this.

Comment: Please define what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to increase the value of the UISlider every 15 minutes? Do you want to fill the UISlider with one time value to another in 15 minute intervals?

Comment: yes i want to increase the value of the UISlider every 15 minutes. like this 4:00, 4:15, 4:30, 4:45 and so next

Comment: I can't make any sense out of your question. You have a slider. You have a sliderMoved method. You want to do *something* with the values from the slider. What, exactly? You want the user's changes to "snap" to 15 minute values, like 4:00, 4:15, etc? So if the user advances the slider a tiny bit, no change and the value is 4:00, but if he changes it a little more, the new value will snap to 4:15? What is the smallest and largest time you want the slider to allow? Or are you saying that every 15 minutes you want the range of values in the slider to change?

Comment: He wants a slider with 4 increments for each hour of the day from 12:00am to 11:45pm of the current day

Comment: @Nik's be aware that a day may not have 24 hours when changing daylight savings time

Comment: @DuncanC
I'm describe my question with more words please suggest me the proper solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For you case, it's better to use some portions scaling. try this code below. I believe it's pretty straightforward.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    let ticksCount: Float = 13*4 // 15mins intervals count from 8am till 9pm
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let todayDate = NSDate()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        slider.minimumValue = 0
        slider.maximumValue = ticksCount
    }

    @IBAction func onValueChanged(slider: UISlider) {

        let minutesFromDayStart = 8 * 60 + Int(slider.value) * 15 // total minutes from day start, assuming we use intervals from 8am
        let timeSlotDate = dateWithTimeSlotForDate(todayDate, minutesFromDayStart: minutesFromDayStart)
        showDate(timeSlotDate)
    }

    private func showDate(date: NSDate) {
        let df = NSDateFormatter()
        df.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
        df.timeStyle = .MediumStyle

        label.text = df.stringFromDate(date)
    }

    private func dateWithTimeSlotForDate(date: NSDate, minutesFromDayStart: Int) -> NSDate {

        let dayStart = dayStartDateForDate(date)
        return calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Minute, value: minutesFromDayStart, toDate: dayStart, options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))!
    }

    private func dayStartDateForDate(date: NSDate) -> NSDate {
        return calendar.startOfDayForDate(date)
    }
}
```

Comment: a very big thanks to you buddy, The perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like

```
  yourSlider.continuous = false


 @IBAction func sliderMoved(sender: UISlider) {

   let slot = Double(sender.value)
   let slotDate = self.timeFromSlot(slot)

   print(timeFormatter.stringFromDate(slotDate!))

   if (sender.value >= 28800 && sender.value < your next interval 1) {
       sender.value  = 28800
   } else if (sender.value >= your next interval 1 && sender.value < your next interval 2) {
       sender.value = your next interval 1
   } else if ....

}
```