# next NSDateFormatter issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

know that there are a lot of similar questions and I need to be more attentive. But I can't understand what's happen in my case.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:a MM/dd/yyyy"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"09:21:am 07/22/2014"];
```

`date` is nil. need a help. thanks.

Comment: I have just tested and it works for me: date contain 2014-07-22 07:21:00 +0000

Comment: Thank you for your help. Will take a look in another place.

Comment: I think the format should be 


    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];

instead   of [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:a MM/dd/yyyy"];

Comment: I don't think it can decide the problem. I found it works in iPhone and is happen only in iPad. Seems to me it's because of time zone

Comment: BTW, it's very non-standard to see the time as `hh:mm:a`. You wouldn't generally use that extra colon. If you need it, go ahead, but it's atypical.

Comment: Thank you for your note. It wasn't mine. I should to fix it only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use 12-hour format for parsing, it seems `NSDateFormatter` needs any 12-hour locale.
I don't know this is a kind of bug or not though.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"es_US"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:a MM/dd/yyyy"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"09:21:am 07/22/2014"];
```

To find 12-hour format locale, this code helps:

```
NSArray *locales = [NSLocale availableLocaleIdentifiers];
for(NSString *locale in locales) {
    NSString *fmt = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"j" options:0 locale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:locale]];
    NSLog(@"%10s:%@", [locale UTF8String], fmt);
}
```

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11660380/3804019)

Comment: Did you mean `en_US`? That's the common locale used. Or `en_US_POSIX` as described in [Technical Q&A QA1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html).

Comment: @Rob Thank you for QA, i didn't know that! it seems `en_US_POSIX` is better. I selected `es_US` because it returns `hh a` not 'h a' for `dateFormatFromTemplate:@"j"` result.