# Is there a better way to format Date with DateFormatter according to user's "Date & Time" preference?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter, dateformatter

My use-case requires me to display different format of strings with respect to user's 12-hour/24-hour preference in "Date & Time" settings.

To be precise, my string needs to ignore the minute component and include the "AM/PM" suffix for 12-hour time and do the exact opposite for the 24-hour time.

I recently got to know about using "jj" template to achieve this. [More on this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49931295/9293498) (Thanks to @larme)

Here's my approach:

```
    let df = DateFormatter()
    df.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("jj:mm") // As of current time in my locale, this'll display "17:01"
    df.locale = .current
    
    if df.string(from: passedDate).count > 5 {
        // User has 12-hour time setting i.e: The string has AM/PM suffix
        df.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("jj") // Setting this will ignore the minutes and provide me with the hour and the AM/PM suffix i.e: "5 PM" according to current time
    }
```

Now, this solves my problem but I wonder if there is a cleaner way to get this done.

Comment: Give an example of how do you want to display the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DateFormatter` static method `dateFormat(fromTemplate tmplate: String, options opts: Int, locale: Locale?) -> String?` passing `j` format and `.current` locale and check if it contains "a":

```
extension DateFormatter {
    static var is24Hour: Bool {
        dateFormat(fromTemplate: "j", options: 0, locale: .current)?.contains("a") == false
    }
}
```

---

```
extension Formatter {
    static let customHour: DateFormatter = {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("jj")
        return dateFormatter
    }()
}
```

---

```
extension Date {
    var customHour: String { Formatter.customHour.string(from: self) }
}
```

---

```
DateFormatter.is24Hour  // false
Date().customHour       // "11 AM"
```

---

---

Note that there is no need to check if 24hour setting is on or not unless the user changes it after the formatter has been initialized. If want to make sure it reflects this as well:

---

```
extension Formatter {
    static let date = DateFormatter()
}
```

---

```
extension Date {
    var customHour: String {
        Formatter.date.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("jj")
        return Formatter.date.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

---

```
Date().customHour       // "11 AM"
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Date` `extension` with `get12HourFormat` and `get24HourFormat`

```
extension Date {
    var get12HourFormat: String? {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a"
        return formatter.string(from: self)
    }
    
    var get24HourFormat: String? {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"
        return formatter.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

**Example:**

```
Date().get12HourFormat //"21-09-2020 07:19 PM"

Date().get24HourFormat //"21-09-2020 19:19"
```

Comment: This has a few issues. First this will be affected by the user's device locale and settings. Second this will create a new DateFormatter every time you call this property.

Comment: This does not respect user's "Date & Time" preference/locale. So say if the user prefers 24-hour time/is in a region that follows 24-hour time, the `get12HourFormat` either returns a wrong string with 24-hour format or even worse `nil` in certain cases. This inconsistency followed by the need to respect user preference is exactly why I went with the "jj" approach